# Handbrake does not find the audio track

Tags: sound, handbrake, transcode

I want to transcode videos using handbrake, but it shows 0 Audio Tracks.

The file is a .mp4 with one video stream (h264) and one audio stream. VLC calls the audio codec "twos" while MediaInfo calls it "PCM (Big / Signed)". It's 48kHz, 16bit, stereo.

The video was recorded by a camera and I used handbrake before to transcode its videos without problems.

Comment: This looks like a problem with a particular program. You should consider contacting [its community](https://handbrake.fr/community.php) to get a more accurate response than from a community of Ubuntu users.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by updating to 1.2.0. I was using 1.1.0 before.

One has to pay attention, though, since after adding the repo (https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases) you have to install *handbrake-gtk* and not *handbrake*

---

Edit:

These are the commands to run to go from v1.1.0 in the regular repo to 1.2.x in the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt update
sudo apt install handbrake-gtk
```